# Kafka Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

What's the difference between the below two dependencies? Do i really need the first one to make a consumer or producer app?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My Producer works fine with just the first one , but the consumer needs the second one.

I had thought the "kafka-clients" artifact would work for both producer and consumer. But looks like "kafka.consumer.Consumer" comes from the other dependency. Why is there a difference?

Also, why is the first artifact named as kafka_2.9.2? i.e why is a version identifier in the name?

Comment: Re: 2.9.2, from the Apache Kafka download page: We build for multiple versions of Scala. This only matters if you are using Scala and you want a version built for the same Scala version you use. Otherwise any version should work (2.10 is recommended).

Comment: Can you add link to the source?

Comment: http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: Perfect! , any idea about the other part of the question?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use the latest producer and consumer API then the correct Maven coordinates are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See the [API documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#api) for more.

Comment: Updated the question to explain my doubt.
Also, 9.0.0.0 is beta as of now.